# React calendar tileclassname

Tags: reactjs, calendar

I want to mark days ,where they are existing in a object array. tileclassname is working when I added one by one. No when I use map, it is not working.

```
tileClassName={({ date, view }) => {
                    if (!props.markDates) return
                    if (
                        moment(date).format("YYYY/MM/DD") <
                        moment().format("YYYY/MM/DD")
                    ) {
                        return "passed";
                    }
                    if (expandDates(props.selectedStart, props.selectedEnd).find((x) => x === moment(date).format("YYYY/MM/DD"))) {
                        return "selected"
                    }
                    props.markDates.map((item) => {
                        if (expandDates(item.dates[0], item.dates[1])[0] === moment(date).format("YYYY/MM/DD")) {
                            return "reserved_check-out";
                        } 
                        else if (expandDates(item.dates[0], item.dates[1])[0] === moment(date).format("YYYY/MM/DD")) {
                            return "reserved_check-in";
                        } 
                        else {
                            return "reserved";
                        }  
                    })
}}
```

How can I use loop in tileclassname?

It is working like that..

```
 if (expandDates(props.markDates[0].dates[0], props.markDates[0].dates[1])[0] === moment(date).format("YYYY/MM/DD")) {
                        return "reserved_check-out";
                    } 
                    else if (expandDates(props.markDates[0].dates[0], props.markDates[0].dates[1])[0] === moment(date).format("YYYY/MM/DD")) {
                        return "reserved_check-in";
                    } 
                    else {
                        return "reserved";
                    }
```